# I don't want my program to wait for a function to finish before moving on to the next task in Python

Tags: python, function

My code looks something like this:

```
def func1():
  page = requests.get(url)
  'click on something'

def func2():
  data = input()
  for x in range(10):
    func1()
    data = input()
```

Basically I want the code to move on and allow the user to enter new data and start another call to `func1()` immediately. However, currently Python waits for the call to `func1()` to finish before moving on.

Comment: you need to look into asynchronous stuff.  there are threads and multiprocess approaches.  best to specify python 2.7 or 3.x, because the multiprocess stuff is slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you need to either use `multithreading` or `multiprocessing`, a simple example using `multithreading`:

```
from threading import Thread

def func1():
  page = requests.get(url)
  'click on something'

def func2():
  data = input()
  for x in range(10):
    t = Thread(target=func1)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    data = input()
```